# Cloud Run Job unauthenticated when scheduled with cloud scheduler, but works fine without scheduler

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

My cloud run jobs keep failing in the cloud scheduler the most recent problem has been that they are unauthenticated, however I give them all the right permissions and execute fine.

They are python scripts that take information from the mouseflow API send it to a temporary dataframe and then send it to bigquery. I changed them as I had the scheduler failing due to it not getting a response, but actually doing the work when I used the code in cloud functions.

But once I used a I try return, else statement the fail went away so the cloud functions are now fine.

The problem with my cloud run jobs is that they execute fine so they appear so have all the correct permissions and service accounts just once they are scheduled they will not work.

I really have no idea why the scheduler is doing this.

Here is the python code:

```
from io import StringIO
import requests

import json

import pandas as pd

from google.cloud import bigquery

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#import schedule

#import time

def rec(request):
    r = requests.get("https://api-eu.mouseflow.com/websites/e768ed54-c09b-48dc-bf49-beda12697013/recordings",

    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("****************", "********************"))

    if r.status_code == 200:
        
        parsed = json.loads(r.text)

        print(json.dumps(parsed['recordings'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(parsed['recordings'])

        #print(df.dtypes) 
      
       
        #df.to_csv('mousedata3.csv')#
        try:
            temp_csv_string = df.to_csv(sep=";", index=False)
            temp_csv_string_IO = StringIO(temp_csv_string)
    # create new dataframe from string variable
            new_df = pd.read_csv(temp_csv_string_IO, sep=";")
    # this new df can be uploaded to BQ with no issues
            new_df.to_gbq('Mouseflow.Mouseflow_Recording', if_exists='replace', project_id='api-data-pod')
            return f'Successful'
        except Exception as err:
            return f'Upload to BigQuery failed: {err}'
    else:
        return f'API request error occurred: Status code {r.status_code}'
rec(requests)
```

And here is the log:

```
{
  "insertId": "1u1op9ffik0vad",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "jobName": "projects/api-data-pod/locations/us-central1/jobs/mouseruningjober",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "url": "https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/api-data-pod/jobs/mouseruningjober:run",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
    "targetType": "HTTP"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 401
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "location": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "api-data-pod",
      "job_id": "mouseruningjober"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-08-09T08:26:20.781273719Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/api-data-pod/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-08-09T08:26:20.781273719Z"
}
```

Comment: You paste a bunch of python code, but cloud scheduler doesn't run code, it only triggers something. Based on the log it looks like you are triggering some cloud run URL? This normally requires authentication headers to be sent by the scheduler, have these been set, and are you sure that the service account used by scheduler has the cloud run invoker role? See https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth

Comment: Hi @somethingsomething I sent the Python code because if I don't put the python code up then someone will say I didn't put my code up and it's a waste of a question. The headers I am using are User-AgentName  Google-Cloud-Scheduler and Content-Type application/json. I have tried several service accounts. My owner one - which has every permission known to man and two specific cloud run invoke service accounts. Am I missing something with the headers?

Comment: Hi @somethingsomething and my understanding of the service account issue is that as long as you did not create it prior to 2019, this Google cloud account was created only in 2021 then the Cloud Scheduler service account is automatically added to your project and has the Cloud Scheduler Service Agent role granted to it. The only service account that you need to manually add if use OIDC is a cloud run invoke account.

Comment: @somethingsomething The only thing that worked was oauth - which I assume is because it is an API and the script uses oauth - and the standard compute engine account. I'm just curious what permissions it has that I don't on for example an owner account or invoker account. It seemed like I had everything needed and even scheduler seemed to think so. Just wondering what I am missing so that I can make accounts other than the standard one that can be used. It's also confusing as pretty much all documentation talk about using oidc.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, the problem was so simple.

I kept trying to use an OIDC token but I actually needed an OAUTH token.

It is really simple, but something that is good to remember as pretty much every guide and tutorial refers to OIDC tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Totally misleading documentation. The solution was to use OAuth and not OIDC. Not sure why everybody suggest OIDC when only OAUTH works.
@user19589395 +1 your answer